# XML AUTO is creating nested element

Tags: sql-server, xml, visual-studio

my xml:auto is creating nested element on performing join so i want to remove nested node of other table..

```
<fo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ss.dbo.FO>
        <aa>10</aa>
        <bb>120</bb>
        <cc>([ads]{})})</cc>
        <stds.dbo.IR>
          <dd>Upmp</dd>
        </ss.dbo.DIR>
      </ss.dbo.FO>
```

Comment: If you have tried something please post your code.

Comment: use the XML:ROW in place of XML:AUTO to Solve this problem XML:AUTO is generating automatic xml for the sql query if you use xml:r--row it will genrate but in simple format without any nested values--

Comment: thanks suraj you tried to help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the XML:ROW in place of XML:AUTO to Solve this problem XML:AUTO is generating automatic xml for the sql query if you use xml:r--row it will genrate but in simple format without any nested values-- –  PANKAJ 786 Dec 13 at 10:39